# Array.ForEach cannot infer array element type from usage

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda

```
public class MyType
{
    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class CustomArray
{
    public MyType this[int index]
    {
        //some code
    }
}

var intList = new List<int>();
var arr = new CustomArray();
Array.ForEach(arr, x => intList.Add(x.MyProperty));
```

This will not compile saying:

> The type arguments for method void System.Array.ForEach(T[],
>   Action) cannot be inferred from the usage.

How can that be?

Comment: Just because your `CustomArray` class has an indexer that doesn't make it an array. It don't think it's possible to create custom arrays the way you're trying to do.

Comment: @xanatos: No it isn't sealed. In particular, `Array` is the base type for any *actual* array type (e.g. `string[]`). You can't derive from it, but only because it's special - not because it's sealed in the normal way. In particular, `typeof(Array).IsSealed` returns false.

Comment: And interestingly, `typeof(Array).IsArray` also returns false

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CustomArray` type is not an array, it's a custom type with an indexed property.

The [`ForEach<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) method expects an array with elements of type `T`, and it didn't get one.

Just because you can use the same operator ([`[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3hd7ste.aspx)) on both and array and an indexed property, does not mean they are the same thing. For example, arrays are sequential by nature, meaning that if `a[0]` and `a[2]` exist, that implies the existence of `a[1]`. Indexed properties, on the other hand, are more like methods that get a parameter, and they are free to do with it whatever they want.

---

If you want to declare an array of `MyType` objects, you do not need to do any special declarations, you can just do:

```
var arr = new MyType[10];
```

and now you have an array that can house 10 `MyType` objects. Initially the values in any of the array's slots is `null` (assuming `MyType` is a class).

Also I would steer clear of the `Array.ForEach` method, I'd prefer using a simple for or foreach loop, or maybe, in this particular case, the `List.AddRange` method:

```
intList.AddRange(arr.Select(x=> x.MyProperty));
```